# EchoSign Embedd Widget with multiple signers

Tags: symfony, echosign

I want to embedd a widget in my application and be able to add **2 signers(recepients)** to it without the sender required to sign the document.
The EchoSign docuemtation says that
"**In the case of a reusable document that needs to be signed by multiple people, it is more efficient to call createEmbeddedWidget once and then call personalizeEmbeddedWidget for each signer.**"

I've tried this method but when I call the personalizeEmbeddedWidget function second time, it replaces the first recepient with the latest one instead of adding a new.

code:

```
                $r = $s->createEmbeddedWidget(array(
                    'apiKey'=>ApiKey,
                    'widgetInfo'=>array(
                        'name'=>'Contract',
                        'fileInfos' => array(
                            'FileInfo' => array(
                                array(
                                'file'     => $file2,
                                'fileName' => $filename2,
                                'mimeType' => 'text/html',
                                ),
                                )
                            ),
                        'widgetCompletionInfo'=>array(
                            'url'=>  return-to-url,
                            'deframe'=> true,
                        ),
                        'signatureFlow'=>'SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED',
                    )
                ));

                if($r->embeddedWidgetCreationResult->success == 1){
                    $widgetCreationScript = $r->embeddedWidgetCreationResult->javascript;

                    $re = $s->personalizeEmbeddedWidget(array(
                                'apiKey'=>$ApiKey,
                                'widgetJavascript' =>  $widgetCreationScript,
                                'personalizationInfo' => array(
                                    'email' => 1st_email_address,
                                )
                    ));
                    $widgetScript = $re->embeddedWidgetCreationResult->javascript;
                    $docKey = $r->embeddedWidgetCreationResult->documentKey;

                    $re1 = $s->personalizeEmbeddedWidget(array(
                                'apiKey'=>$ApiKey,
                                'widgetJavascript' => $widgetScript,
                                'personalizationInfo' => array(
                                    'email' => 2nd_email_address,
                                )
                    ));  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The version19 release provides a solution to this problem by adding the ability to add "counter signers" to a widget.

After the first signer completes the widget, the subsequent signer(s) get an email when it is their turn to sign.

But you can't have 2 signers sign a specific contract at the same time using the same link/screen.